# Tools for regression testing / test automation of database centric java application?

Tags: java, testing

I'm looking for a good, preferably free tool for automating tests of a java (EJB3) application without any kind of GUI.

Tool should be capable of at least:

- Inserting / updating / deleting data on database
- Querying and comparing data on database
- Reading and writing to FTP server
- Initializing test environment, launching EJB3 bean, cleaning up test environment after the test
- Reporting
- Some kind of scripting interface is enough, no GUI required

Naturally this could be done using Java & JUnit but it would be pretty tedious. I would appreciate any hints of such tools.

Comment: [Here is a HUGE list of open sources solutions.](http://www.manageability.org/blog/stuff/open-source-automated-test-tools-written-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Robot framework, Fitnesse and Concordion seem currently the most interesting candidates.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are looking for a combination of DBUnit and Cactus (the FTP stuff might require Commons-NET or Commons-VFS). Use ANT, with its scripting support, to get the reporting on the test results and the scripting.

That hits the checklist. If you want to test those EJB's out of the container, there is EJB3Unit.

Comment: I'm looking for something a bit more higher level. Some kind of script based system.