# How to best test Java code?

Tags: java, testing, interface, junit

I have been working on a comparatively large system on my own, and it's my first time working on a large system(dealing with 200+ channels of information simultaneously). I know how to use Junit to test every method, and how to test boundary conditions. But still, for system test, I need to test all the interfacing and probably so some stress test as well (maybe there are other things to do, but I don't know what they are). I am totally new to the world of testing, and please give me some suggestions or point me to some info on how a good code tester would do system testing.

PS: 2 specific questions I have are:
how to test private functions? 
how to testing interfaces and avoid side effects?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are two web sites that might help:

The first is a list of [open source Java tools](http://java-source.net/open-source/testing-tools).  Many of the tools are addons to JUnit that allow either easier testing or testing at a higher integration level.

Depending on your system, sometimes JUnit will work for system tests, but the structure of the test can be different.

As for private methods, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105007/do-you-test-private-method) (and the question it references).

You cannot test interfaces (as there is no behavior), but you can create an abstract base test classes for testing that implementations of an interface follow its contract.

EDIT:  Also, if you don't already have unit tests, check out [Working Effectivly with Legacy Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131177052); it is a must for testing code that is not set up well for testing.

Comment: I ordered the book just now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

[Mocking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) is a good way to be able to simulate system tests in unit testing; by replacing (mocking) the resources upon which the other component depends, you can perform unit testing in a "system-like" environment without needing to have the entire system constructed to do it.

As to your specific questions: generally, you shouldn't be using unit testing to test private functions; if they're private, they're **private** to the class.  If you need to test something, test a public method which uses that private method to do something.  Avoiding side effects that can be potentially problematic is best done using either a complete test environment (which can easily be wiped back to a "virgin" state) or using mocking, as described above.  And testing interfaces is done by, well, testing the interface methods.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, if you already have a large system that doesn't have any unit tests, and you're planning on adding some, then allow me to offer some general advice.

From maintaining the system and working with it, you'll probably already know the areas of the system which tend to be buggiest, which tend to change often and which tend not to change very much. If you don't, you can always look through the source control logs (you are using source control, right?) to find out where most of the bug fixes and changes are concentrated. Focus your testing efforts on these classes and methods. There's a general rule called the *80/20 rule* which is applicable to a whole range of things, this being one of them.

It says that, roughly on average, you should be able to cover 80 percent of the offending cases by doing just 20% of the work. That is, by writing tests for just 20% of the code, you can probably catch 80% of the bugs and regressions. That's because most of the fragile code, commonly changed code and worst offending code makes up just 20% of the codebase. In fact, it may be even less.

You should use junit to do this and you should use something like [JMock](http://www.jmock.org/) or some other mocking library to ensure you're testing in isolation. For system testing/integration testing, that is, testing things while they're working together, I can recommend [FitNesse](http://fitnesse.org/). I've had good experience with it in the past. It allows you to write your test in a web browser using simple table-like layouts, where you can easily define your inputs and expected outputs. All you have to do is write a small backing class called a Fixture, which handles the creation of the components.

Answer (score 2):

Private functions will be tested when the public functions that call them. Your testing of the public function only cares that the result returned is correct.

When dealing with API (to other packages or URLS or even to file/network/database) you should mock them. A good unit test should run in a few milliseconds not in seconds. Mocking is the only way to do that. It means that bugs between packages can be dealt with a lot easier than logical bugs at the functional level. For Java [easymock](http://easymock.org/) is a very good mocking framework.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a look on this list : [Tools for regression testing / test automation of database centric java application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105620/tools-for-regression-testing-test-automation-of-database-centric-java-applicati) for a list of interesting tools.

As you seem to already use Junit extensively it means that you're already "test infected", that is a good point...

In my personal experience, the most difficult thing to manage is data. I mean, controlling very acutely the data agaisnt which the tests are runned.

Answer (score 0):

The lists of tools given before are useful. From personal experience these are the tools I find useful:

Mocking -  **Mockito** is an excellent implementation and has clever techniques to ensure you only have to mock the methods you really care about.

Database testing - **DBunit** is indespensible for setting up test data and verifying database interactions.

Stress testing - **Jmeter** - once you see passed the slightly clunky gui this is a very robust tool for setting up scenarios and running stress tests.

As for general approach start by trying to get tests running for the usual "happy paths" through your application these can form a basis for regression testing and performance testing. Once this is complete you can start looking at edge cases and error scenarios.

Although this level of testing should be secondary to good unit testing.

Good luck!