# Is it necessary to test each method individually?

Tags: java, junit

I am writing Unit tests for my controller methods and many of the methods call on other methods which then also calls on other methods until finally returning a result. Now from what I have read on best practices one should test each method even if it has been essentially "tested" through another method.

To put this in perspective lets say I have these 3 methods and I do an assertTrue(MethodA) is it really necessary that I test MethodB and then MethodC as well? If so why?

```
  public Boolean MethodA(Object o)
    {
        try {
            //Do stuff
            return MethodB(Object o);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public Boolean MethodB(Object o)
    {
        try {
            //Do stuff
            return MethodC(Object o);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public Boolean MethodC(Object o)
    {
        try {
            //Do stuff with o
            //return True
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would test them individually, because all methods are public and the cascading calls are an implementation detail

Comment: The methods are public, there's no guarantee that `methodA` is the only caller of `methodB` and `methodC`, so if they are not tested, other callers may break when they change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on you and your team actually. In this case I would probably test them all.

One reason being: how else could I ensure that when `methodA()` returned `false` that it is due to the calculation that was done in `methodB()` or an exception from there? Same question applies to `methodC()` as well... if there is thrown an exception we get `false`, but how should I know whether (actually: ensure that) it was due to an exception or from an actual calculation?

If you would test that through `methodA()` only that test alone will probably become way too complex and you would add too much logic of the inner workings to that specific test(s). Try to test/challenge your method from an outside view. Everything that is visible from outside you probably want to test alone. Also: keep your tests simple enough that when you return you can easily grasp why you tested it this way.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you should test them all. At some point in the future the implementation of one of the calling methods, say `MethodA`, may change and you need to test if all the old uses are still applicable. There are several points I would considered in this situation:

- Is it really necessary to have all this methods just calling another method that is calling another method, etc? I mean, if all methods are public, why should an external object call `MethodA` and not directly `MethodC`? I'm not saying you must eliminate all internal call, but a public method should expose a unique functionality, and each functionality should be available only through one method.
- Could you make some of the methods private? if you have this kind of nested calls to reuse code, you should encapsulate the called methods by avoiding external objects to call them, because they are effectively implementation detail, and not part of the exposed functionalities.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this Question [How to best test Java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1139136/10606957). 
There are some good advices on how to test and how much of your code you need to test
(Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1139266/10606957 explaines the 80:20 approach in programming).
Even if those answers aim at some bigger projects, it might be good to learn those things from scratch.

NOTE: Would have made this a comment but I haven´t unlocked comments jet ^^